# Python and Flask: Help on combining Add and Remove under one @app.route

Tags: javascript, python, html, json, flask

I need assistance connecting the **add and remove routes under one route**. The idea is to save data in a JSON file. Then later if I enter **the same data** in the JSON file, the app will recognize it as already being in the JSON file and ask if **I want to keep it or remove it**. The app is already set up to add data to certain JSON files selected from a drop-down box. But I also want to be able to remove/delete certain data from those JSON files. I have the add and remove code under separate @app.routes. I am not sure how to combine them under one @app.route and have the prompt **ask to keep or delete**. My code is below. I am new to all of this and created this from watching a few tutorials online. Expert help is definitely welcomed. Thank you for your time.

Flask app.py

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, abort, jsonify, Response
import os
from os.path import abspath, join, isfile
import logging
import json

os.environ['FLASK_APP'] = 'PermissionsHashes'
os.environ['FLASK_ENV'] = 'development'

log = logging.getLogger('hashhost')
log.setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)

password = "password"

dataFolder = join(abspath(os.getcwd()), "Data")

app = Flask("PermissionsHashHost")

app.template_folder = join(abspath(os.getcwd()), "Templates")


@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template("add_new.html", perms=[x for x in os.listdir(dataFolder) if x.endswith(".json")])


@app.route('/<string:requested_file>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def base(requested_file):
    f = join(dataFolder, requested_file)
    print "requested: ", f, "method: ", request.method

    if not isfile(f):
        if isfile(f + ".json"):
            f += ".json"
        else:
            abort(404)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        with open(f, "r") as q:
            return jsonify([x.encode("utf-8") if isinstance(x, unicode) else x for x in json.loads(q.read())])
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        if isinstance(request.form['text'], basestring):
            if str(request.form['pass']) == password:
                v = request.form['text']
                if isinstance(v, unicode):
                    v = v.encode("utf-8")

                print "Adding provided client: ", v, " to list "

                with open(f, "r") as q:
                    data = [x.encode("utf-8") if isinstance(x, unicode) else x for x in json.loads(q.read())]

                if v in data:
                    r = "Provided client is already in the list"
                    print r
                    return r
                else:
                    data.append(v)
                    with open(f, "w") as q:
                        q.write(json.dumps(data, encoding="utf-8"))
                        r = "Provided client is added to the list"
                        print r
                        return r
            else:
                r = Response(response="Wrong Password Provided", status=401)
                print r
                return r
        else:
            r = Response(response="Input Must Be A Valid String", status=400)
            print r
            return r


@app.route('/<string:requested_file>/remove', methods=['POST'])
def remove(requested_file):
    f = join(dataFolder, requested_file)
    print "requested: ", f, "method: ", request.method

    if not isfile(f):
        if isfile(f + ".json"):
            f += ".json"
        else:
            abort(404)

    if isinstance(request.form['text'], basestring):
        if str(request.form['pass']) == password:
            v = request.form['text']
            if isinstance(v, unicode):
                v = v.encode("utf-8")

            print "Removing provided client: ", v, " from list "

            with open(f, "r") as q:
                data = [x.encode("utf-8") if isinstance(x, unicode) else x for x in json.loads(q.read())]

            if v not in data:
                r = "Provided client is not in the list"
                print r
                return r
            else:
                data.remove(v)
                with open(f, "w") as q:
                    q.write(json.dumps(data, encoding="utf-8"))
                    r = "Provided client is removed from the list"
                    print r
                    return r
        else:
            r = 'Wrong Password Provided'
            print r
            return r
    else:
        r = 'Input Must Be A Valid String'
        print r
        return r


"""@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(error):
    return render_template('404.html', title='404'), 404"""

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run("0.0.0.0", 5000)
```

add_new.html template

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Add new player permission</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function OnFormSubmit() {
            let permission = document.getElementById("perm").value;
            let text = document.getElementById("client_str").value;
            console.log(permission);
            console.log(text);
        }

        function OnPermsChange() {
            document.getElementById("form").action = "/" + document.getElementById("perm").value;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="OnPermsChange()">
<h1>Hello World</h1>
<h3>Submit the following form with the data.</h3>
<form method="post" id="form" onload="OnPermsChange()">
    <label for="client_str">Client String (without quotes):</label><input type="text" name="text" id="client_str"><br>
    <label for="password">Your password:</label><input type="password" name="pass" id="password"><br>

    <label for="perm">Choose a permission:</label>
    <select name="perm" id="perm" onchange="OnPermsChange()">
        {% for p in perms %}
            <option value="{{ p }}">{{ p[:-5] }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select><br>

    <input type="submit" onload="OnPermsChange()">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by adding a button to each function!

Flask app.py

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, abort, jsonify, Response
import os
from os.path import abspath, join, isfile
import logging
import json

os.environ['FLASK_APP'] = 'PermissionsHashes'
os.environ['FLASK_ENV'] = 'development'

log = logging.getLogger('hashhost')
log.setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)

password = "password"

dataFolder = join(abspath(os.getcwd()), "Data")

app = Flask("PermissionsHashHost")

app.template_folder = join(abspath(os.getcwd()), "Templates")


@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template("add_new.html", perms=[x for x in os.listdir(dataFolder) if x.endswith(".json")])


@app.route('/<string:requested_file>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def base(requested_file):
    f = join(dataFolder, requested_file)
    print "requested: ", f, "method: ", request.method

    if not isfile(f):
        if isfile(f + ".json"):
            f += ".json"
        else:
            abort(404)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        with open(f, "r") as q:
            return jsonify([x.encode("utf-8") if isinstance(x, unicode) else x for x in json.loads(q.read())])
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['submit_button'] == 'Add':
            pass # do something
            if isinstance(request.form['text'], basestring):
                if str(request.form['pass']) == password:
                    v = request.form['text']
                    if isinstance(v, unicode):
                        v = v.encode("utf-8")

                    print "Adding provided client: ", v, " to list "

                    with open(f, "r") as q:
                        data = [x.encode("utf-8") if isinstance(x, unicode) else x for x in json.loads(q.read())]

                    if v in data:
                        r = "Provided client is already in the list"
                        print r
                        return r, {"Refresh": "3; url=https://link_to_your_app"}
                    else:
                        data.append(v)
                        with open(f, "w") as q:
                            q.write(json.dumps(data, encoding="utf-8"))
                            r = "Provided client is added to the list"
                            print r
                            return r, {"Refresh": "3; url=https://link_to_your_app"}
                else:
                    r = Response(response="Wrong Password Provided", status=401)
                    print r
                    return r, {"Refresh": "3; url=https://link_to_your_app"}
            else:
                r = Response(response="Input Must Be A Valid String", status=400)
                print r
                return r, {"Refresh": "3; url=https://link_to_your_app"}

        elif request.form['submit_button'] == 'Remove':
            pass # do something else
            if isinstance(request.form['text'], basestring):
                if str(request.form['pass']) == password:
                    v = request.form['text']
                    if isinstance(v, unicode):
                        v = v.encode("utf-8")

                    print "Removing provided client: ", v, " from list "

                    with open(f, "r") as q:
                        data = [x.encode("utf-8") if isinstance(x, unicode) else x for x in json.loads(q.read())]

                    if v not in data:
                        r = "Provided client is not in the list"
                        print r
                        return r, {"Refresh": "3; url=https://link_to_your_app"}
                    else:
                        data.remove(v)
                        with open(f, "w") as q:
                            q.write(json.dumps(data, encoding="utf-8"))
                            r = "Provided client is removed from the list"
                            print r
                            return r, {"Refresh": "3; url=https://link_to_your_app"}
                else:
                    r = Response(response="Wrong Password Provided", status=401)
                    print r
                    return r, {"Refresh": "3; url=https://link_to_your_app"}
            else:
                r = Response(response="Input Must Be A Valid String", status=400)
                print r
                return r, {"Refresh": "3; url=https://link_to_your_app"}

"""@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(error):
    return render_template('404.html', title='404'), 404"""

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run("0.0.0.0", 5000)
```

add_new.html template

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Add new player permission</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function OnFormSubmit() {
            let permission = document.getElementById("perm").value;
            let text = document.getElementById("client_str").value;
            console.log(permission);
            console.log(text);
        }

        function OnPermsChange() {
            document.getElementById("form").action = "/" + document.getElementById("perm").value;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="OnPermsChange()">
<h1>Hello World</h1>
<h3>Submit the following form with the data.</h3>
<form method="post" id="form" onload="OnPermsChange()">
    <label for="client_str">Client String (without quotes):</label><input type="text" name="text" id="client_str"><br>
    <label for="password">Your password:</label><input type="password" name="pass" id="password"><br>

    <label for="perm">Choose a permission:</label>
    <select name="perm" id="perm" onchange="OnPermsChange()">
        {% for p in perms %}
            <option value="{{ p }}">{{ p[:-5] }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select><br>

    <input type="submit" name="submit_button" onload="OnPermsChange()" value="Add">
    <input type="submit" name="submit_button" onload="OnPermsChange()" value="Remove">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```